# iScroll 4 Cant Scroll right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iscroll4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IScroll wrapper doesnt get a height.!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459864/iscroll-wrapper-doesnt-get-a-height)

my Code is like following:

```
<div id ="wrapper" data-role="content" height="100%">
            <div id="scroller">
                <div class="homebutton_zeile">
                    <a id="picture_home" href="#pictrues">
                        <div class="homebutton_all">
                           <div class="homebutton_name">Picture</div>
                            <div class="homebutton_picture">
                             <img src="images/picture.png" alt="image" style="position: relative; width:100%;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the Scroller div says, that there is no height to scroll. So i could move it with the mouse but it will not shown right if i got more than this at the same page in the wrapper.

Can anyone help me there please?

Comment: Did you copy the code correctly? You are missing a closing div tag.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot the div tag to copy. In My code the div tag is allready there, but thx :). Can Anybody help me there? Its Important.